# Negative vibes & environment at new workplace, is it normal?

Tags: professionalism, management, burnout

I would just like to ask for opinions on this matter.

I started working at this company on new year (small company with 30+ staff). During my probation, I started to feel burnouts. FYI, I'm the youngest in this company & as a 2nd higher bosses, unfortunately my board of directors & apparently all the staff can't accept the way I'm controlling the cash flow.

I noticed that previously before I joined, the claims for mileage, annual leave etc, has been processed daily but when I came in, I set it to monthly, and some of the BOD & staff even claimed for what they're not entitled for. I'm honestly quite shock with this environment & there's no integrity at all controlling the company's money... the list goes on when we talked about all the unnecessary expenses by BOD..

Is this kind of behaviour normal at other company? I just feel that I landed at wrong place as the vibes here is too negative & they didn't know how to become a professional, even the BOD.. its so contrary from my previous company (airlines industry) when all people were very welcoming to new people & not stingy with their knowledge.

As the youngest, I always pay respect to the senior staff regardless their position but I'm kinda sad. I wish to upgrade & bring the best out of this company potential but whenever I voice out my opinions, they would say that I'm being arrogant & as the youngest, I shouldn't share any immature idea.. Gosh... all my ideas I share with them were after discussion with bank, other financial institution, government etc.

I'm 26 and I already feel that this kind of life is sucks being an unwanted & youngest boss

Comment: What country is this in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's multiple factors here that are working against you in this situation, some are things you can control (if you choose) and others aren't:

1. You're having an effect on people's finances that the perceive negatively:

> I noticed that previously before I joined, the claims for mileage, annual leave etc, has been processed daily.. but when I came in, I set it to monthly..

While I'm not saying what you did was wrong - it sounds like a reasonable change in all honesty. But that now means that people who were used to getting reimbursed for stuff relatively immediately are now waiting up to a month for it. That's a bigger change for some people than you might think - sure they get their money eventually but for weeks they don't have it available to them. If someone is living paycheck-to-paycheck then that can be *uncomfortable* to say the least, I wouldn't suggest going back to the old way necessarily but you could offer that if staff have extenuating circumstances where they need the money back sooner then you can be flexible. That way you are showing that you aren't insensitive to the potential impact of these changes but you still have the system you wanted.

> some of the BOD & staff even claimed for what they're not entitled for..

People don't generally like getting caught doing things they weren't supposed to be doing - and that goes *double* for when it's leaving them worse off then they were before. Again I'm not saying you were in the wrong here - I dislike people taking the mickey with expenses as much as the next guy but it's not going to endear you to them.

2. You're young.

It's not fair, it's not right, and it's far from something you can control but the truth is that many people dislike being told what to do by those younger than them. There *are* however aspects of your youth that you can control so that the perception of you diverges from the stereotype older people may have of people your age. If you act/dress/speak/write like someone older than their years over time people will start to *think* of you that way. Is it fair that you should have to work hard to make up for something that's purely a perception thing? No - but the world **isn't** fair.

Case in point - your post here, while this may not reflect your professional communications and demeanor it's all I've got to go on to form a perception of you - and frankly you come across as a good deal younger than 26. If you didn't mention your age I'd be hard pressed to say you were older than 13-14!

To be honest it makes it very hard to give your words or concerns any weight, even though you list some very valid ones (people abusing expenses etc) - and this is just a post on Workplace SE. If this was a work communication I'd think it was a joke - and likely that you were too.

This is not intended to make you feel bad - just to illustrate that the way people perceive *you* also hugely influences they way they perceive what you are saying.

Maybe this job just isn't going to work out well - could be a case of that over-used term "a bad fit" but that's not a call I can make for you.

Comment: Great answer. I was thinking by the second paragraph, "Man, this guy in in charge of the cash flow?" Then I got to the end and he's 26? I'm not ageist, but the way you're presenting your argument, in addition to your lack of awareness of how your changes are impacting your employees makes me think you're in over your head. Sure, you may understand finances, but unless you change your approach and how you handle criticism/complaints, you're not going to be there for long. And in that case, I wouldn't be blaming the BOD or the employees.